# gprof on both OpenMP and without OpenMP codes produces different flat profile

Tags: openmp, gprof

After successfully implementing OpenMP to my code, I am trying to check how much the implementation has improved my code performance, but using gprof it gives me totally different flat profile. Below is my main program calling all subroutines.

```
program main
  use my_module
  call inputf       !to read inputs from a file
! call echo         !to check if the inputs are read in correctly, but is muted
  call allocv       !to allocate dimension to all array variable
  call bathyf       !to read in the computational domain
  call inicon       !to setup initial conditions
  call comput       !computation from iteration 1 to n
  call deallv       !to deallocate all array variables
end program main
```

Following is the `cpu_time` and `OMP_GET_WTIME()` for both serial and parallel codes. The OpenMP parallel region is within `subroutine comput`.

```
!serial code
CPU time elapsed =   260.5080 seconds.
!parallel code
CPU time elapsed =   153.3600 seconds.
OMP time elapsed =    49.3521 seconds.
```

And the following are the flat profile for both serial and parallel codes.

```
!Serial code
Flat profile:
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name
 96.26    227.63   227.63        1   227.63   236.45  comput_
  3.60    236.13     8.50     2001     0.00     0.00  update_
  0.08    236.32     0.19     2000     0.00     0.00  openbc_
  0.05    236.45     0.13       41     0.00     0.00  output_
  0.01    236.47     0.02        1     0.02     0.02  bathyf_
  0.01    236.49     0.02        1     0.02     0.03  inicon_
  0.00    236.50     0.01        1     0.01     0.01  opwmax_
  0.00    236.50     0.00     1001     0.00     0.00  timser_
  0.00    236.50     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  timestamp_
  0.00    236.50     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  allocv_
  0.00    236.50     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  deallv_
  0.00    236.50     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  inputf_

!Parallel code
Flat profile:
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name
 95.52     84.90    84.90                             openbc_
  1.68     86.39     1.49     2001     0.74     0.74  update_
  0.10     86.48     0.09       41     2.20     2.20  output_
  0.00     86.48     0.00     1001     0.00     0.00  timser_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  timestamp_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  allocv_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  bathyf_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  deallv_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     2.20  inicon_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  inputf_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  comput_
  0.00     86.48     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  opwmax_
```

`subroutine update`, `openbc`, `output` and `timser` are called within `subroutine comput`. As you can see, the `subroutine comput` is suppose to spend the most runtime, but the flat profile of the parallel code shows otherwise. Please let me know if you need other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gprof` is poorly suited for analysis of parallel programs as it doesn't understand the intricacies of OpenMP. You should instead use something like a combination of [Score-P](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/) and [Cube](http://www.scalasca.org/software/cube-4.x/download.html). The former is an instrumentation framework while the latter is a visualisation tool for hierarchical performance data. Both are open-source projects. On the commercial front, Intel VTune Amplifier could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the tools recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html) says:

> One problem with gprof under certain kernels (such as Linux) is that it doesn’t behave correctly with multithreaded applications. It actually only profiles the main thread, which is quite useless.

The article also provides a work-around, but since you don't create your threads manually, but instead use OpenMP (which creates the threads transparently), you will have to modify it to make it work for you.

You could also choose a profiler that is able to work with parallel programs instead.

Comment: The solution presented in the article should work with most OpenMP runtimes, e.g. libgomp, as they usually rely on pthreads for their thread support anyway.